# file system permissions for samba share

Tags: unix, filesystems, samba

I have an issue with file system permissions when using samba on my raspi.

It worked previously, then it stopped working. I suspect something with the file system.

It is about the folder `/media/usb/4tb/backups`.

When I do a `cd /media/usb/4tb && ls -lsah` this is the stripped output:

```
4.0K drwxr-xr-x 2 keeper keeper 4.0K Oct 20 15:58 backups
```

There is a user `keeper` and I  did a

```
sudo chown -R keeper:  backups
```

But when I connect to my mac via:

```
mount_smbfs //keeper@10.0.0.3/backups ./mntpoint
```

To try:

```
touch: hi: Permission denied
```

When I change permissions to 777 for this folder on my raspi:

```
4.0K drwxrwxrwx 2 keeper keeper 4.0K Oct 20 15:58 backups
```

I create a file via `touch hi` via my connected mac, this works:

```
➜  backups ls -lsah
total 8.0K
4.0K drwxrwxrwx 2 keeper keeper 4.0K Oct 20 16:04 .
4.0K drwxr-xr-x 6 root   root   4.0K Oct 20 15:45 ..
   0 -rwxr--r-- 1 keeper keeper    0 Oct 20 16:04 hi
```

But when I want to create a folder via my connected mac:

```
➜  mntpoint mkdir folder
➜  mntpoint touch folder/hiho
touch: folder/hiho: Permission denied
➜  mntpoint
```

And when I look on my raspi:

```
➜  backups ls -lsah
total 12K
4.0K drwxrwxrwx 3 keeper keeper 4.0K Oct 20 16:05 .
4.0K drwxr-xr-x 6 root   root   4.0K Oct 20 15:45 ..
4.0K drwxr-xr-x 2 keeper keeper 4.0K Oct 20 16:05 folder
   0 -rwxr--r-- 1 keeper keeper    0 Oct 20 16:04 hi
```

I am confused. The folder is owned by `keeper`. Why is it not allowed for this user to create files inside his own folder?

It worked before.. so I suspect something with the file system rather to the smb conf.

But just in case, this is my `testparm`output:

```
[global]
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    logging = file
    map to guest = Bad User
    max log size = 1000
    obey pam restrictions = Yes
    pam password change = Yes
    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
    passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
    passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
    security = USER
    server role = standalone server
    server string = North Dakota %v
    unix password sync = Yes
    usershare allow guests = Yes
    idmap config * : backend = tdb


[backups]
    comment = Backups
    path = /media/4tb/backups
    read only = No
    valid users = keeper
    vfs objects = catia fruit streams_xattr
    fruit:time machine = yes


[share]
    comment = Share
    path = /media/4tb/share
    read only = No
    valid users = sharer
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by creating a new user, while keeping the exact same smb.cnf and folder structure.. weird thing.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.